# Assigning NA to specific rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of 756 columns and 1448 rows. In columns 9:756 I am trying to place NA's in every 3rd and 4th row. Some of the rows (from 9:756) already have NA's, but because my data set is so large, I do not want to go it 1 by 1, so thought I could just list all the columns and assign those rows to NA. This is the code that I tried to use:

> removed_twins_Species[,9:756][seq(from = 4, to = 1448, by = 4)] <- NA

But, I came up with this error:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, seq(from = 4, to = 1448, by = 4), value = NA) :
new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Any help with this would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: `seq(from = 4, to = 1448, by = 4)` is every 4th row only and not 3rd and 4th row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vector recycling to replace every 3rd and 4th row in columns 9 to 756 with `NA`.

```
removed_twins_Species[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),9:756] <- NA
```

An example with `mtcars` data :

```
df <- mtcars
df[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), 3:10] <- NA
df

#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Duster 360          14.3   8    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA    4
#Merc 240D           24.4   4    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA    2
#...
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

See `1:13 %% 4 == 0` will return every fourth row, similarly `1:nrow(df) %% 4 %in% c(0, 3)` will return `TRUE` for every third and fourth row.

Thus, you can also do

```
removed_twins_Species[1:nrow(df) %% 4 %in% c(0,3), 9:756] <- NA
```